# Delphi RESTDebugger GET Request URL Encoded hash %23 not working

Tags: rest, delphi, url-encoding

I need to get a simple REST GET call worked, e.g.

```
.../process('123')  -> working
.../process('123#') -> of course not working
.../process('123%23') -> should be working
```

In the REST-Tool "Postman" it's working with the encoded URL, i.e. # -> %23

I tried it with the following settings

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Both not working.

Please advice
Thanks
Ralph

Comment: If you use ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.EchoString('%123%') from the Assistant generated Restserver/Client projects you will see what happens the result will be 3% . I'd suspect EncodeURIComponent in Datasnap.DSClientRest being the culprit. Something like this seems to happen: `Edit1.Text := 'Param=%123%';
  Edit2.Text :=  EncodeURIComponent(Edit1.Text) ;
  Edit3.Text := TNetEncoding.URL.Decode(Edit2.Text) ;`

Comment: I'd suspect the problem would be solved with changing  `Result := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(AStr, UnsafeChars, []);` to `Result := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(AStr, UnsafeChars, [TURLEncoding.TEncodeOption.EncodePercent]);`  in EncodeURIComponent .

Answer (score 0):

EncodeURIComponent in the unit Datasnap.DSClientRest causes the same problem for me.

My fix was to copy the unit to source directory and to change the function EncodeURIComponent to change the options of TNetEncoding.URL.Encode from `[]` to `[TURLEncoding.TEncodeOption.EncodePercent]` so the new resultline would look like:

```
Result := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(AStr, UnsafeChars, [TURLEncoding.TEncodeOption.EncodePercent]);
```

The reason is that, if called without `[TURLEncoding.TEncodeOption.EncodePercent]` the part

```
if not(TEncodeOption.EncodePercent in Options) and (I + 2 < Len) and (Buff[I] = Ord('%')) and
    IsHexChar(Buff[I + 1]) and IsHexChar(Buff[I + 2]) then
  begin
    Result := Result + '%' + Char(Buff[I + 1]) + Char(Buff[I + 2]);
    Inc(I, 3);
  end
```

will not encode % if the two following characters are valid hex characters.